# Orchard CMS ContentPart Update

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to send a message every time a specific Content Part is updated, created or deleted.

When is created or deleted I use the Content Handler: OnCreated and OnRemoving to send the message.

But during the update I need the previous state of the ContentPart and the new Data also.

Thanks.

[Answer]

The answer and comments of [Piotr Szmyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629335/piotr-szmyd) lead me to the solve the problem. Read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OnVersioning` / `OnVersioned`. Those events gets fired whenever a new version of an item is created. You can access old and new versions of a given part then.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in the OnVersioned/Versioning the Existing and Building Parts kept the same information. So what I do is: use a private string in the ContentHandler where in OnUpdating I save the current info and in OnUpdated send the new and the old info stored in that string. As the Handler is instantiated per request, the string is only used during the OnUpdating/OnUpdated cycle.

Comment: The problem why you see both existing/building parts the same is because those parts are not versionable (ie. the underlying record derives from `ContentPartRecord`, not the `ContentPartVersionRecord`. The example of versionable parts are eg. `BodyPart`, `CommonPart`. Take a look at the implementations of those parts to see how it should be done.

Comment: But of course, you may have your own mechanism for keeping track of the changes, sure (saving the initial state in `OnLoaded` and using it in `OnUpdated`). Please bear in mind that content handler is not instantiated per-item (only per-request, as you said), so you may need to use eg. a dictionary (with item id as a key) instead of a simple private string. Otherwise you won't be able to tell what item is the currently stored string value coming from when `OnUpdated` fires.