# Orchard CMS Compute Derived Field on Create / Update

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm building an Orchard content part for location data which include latitude and longitude fields. Whenever content is saved (created or updated), I would like to compute the bounding lat/lng for various max distances (20 miles, 50 miles, etc.) and save for later reference to search within a given radius of a specific location.

I already have all the necessary calculations for geolocation. The problem at hand is actually computing the derived value upon save (create/update), and setting the derived values to new fields on the content part before persisting to its repository.

I have a feeling adding filters like `OnCreated` in the associated ContentHandler might be a step in the right direction, but wasn't able to quickly locate any discussion related to a similar use case. So, I just wanted to reach out to the community and hear your thoughts on this particular problem before I proceed.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with adding an `OnCreated` filter!

You could use `OnUpdateEditorShape` if you are only bothered about detecting when the content item is updated via the dashboard (or more generally, when the content item is updated using `IContentManager.UpdateEditor(...)`).

`OnVersioning`/`OnVersioned` will give you access to the "before" and "after" versions of a content item when it is updated, if your record class inherits from `ContentPartVersionRecord` (this will work with `ContentPartRecord`, but the "before" and "after" parameters will be the same).

You might want to look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978144/orchard-cms-contentpart-update/15994235#15994235).

- Edit: "before" and "after" versions are called `Existing` and `Building` in `VersionContentContext`.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the same about OnUpdateEditorShape. Currently, there is no other scenario where the content is updated; however, I'm always a bit cautious about what might happen in the future ;) I'll tinker and get back with my findings.